# How to get socket connect options in server?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I don't know how to get options from socket client connection.

Client:

```
var socketURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000';

var options = {
    transports: ['websocket'],
    'force new connection': true,
    query: 'token=jnecdodcswoimedwmnoinsdxc'
};
```

Server:

```
sio.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log(socket.query) // this not working
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I want get `query` option from client-side for token.

Comment: I discovered how you can do it and it's all described in the question/answer I marked yours a duplicate of.  It is unfortunate that the socket.io documentation is so lacking in this type of information.